# Check some requirements when running setup.py for install

Tags: python, distutils

I want to check some requirements (but existence of other python packages, I already know how to do that) of the system before running `setup()`, like **check output of some system commands**, to stop installation process and warn user if requirements doesn't met. But I need to do it only when running `setup.py install`, not `setup.py check` or `setup.py sdist`.

How can I do that?

UPD: Example of check that I need:

```
packs = subprocess.check_output(['packagemanager', '--list'])
if NAME in packs:
    print ('You have to remove previous version of %s '
        'before installing this.' % NAME
    )
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You'd use `install_requires`, and you can build that list dynamically too, if required by the python version used to install.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the kind of test you wanted to do?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to install a full-blown application with complex requirements.  Despite the fact that setup.py often gets used for this, it's ill-suited for it - you're much better off using your distribution packaging system of choice (deb/rpm/MSI, etc.) for this type of complex installation (and uninstallation).

Comment: @NickBastin Unfortunately distribution for which I wrote, uses setuptools as packaging system of choice. :)

Comment: How do you check manually whether that particular software is installed or not? Does it create some directory structure after installation or is there any particular message in it's install logs, or a file that is only created if it is installed? ;) Just check this and then only call python setup.py install.

Comment: @Drt well, user runs setup.py. And if it run it when some software is installed, there will be no other way for him to recover the system, except for full reinstall, or recovering to  a snapshot. That is the problem. :)

Comment: @Bunyk That's what I am saying, run "python setup.py install" only after a condition passes i.e. if condition, lets say. This condition is check of installation (what I mentioned in previous comment) i.e. check a particular dir struct., file, log etc. is created. Let me know whether this clears the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what i'll do. I'll just look into `sys.argv` to see if `install` param was passed into `setup.py`, before calling `setup()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[PACKAGE1, PACKAGE2]
)
```

Comment: What exactly I need, is to check that some software is NOT installed, and that software is not a python packages. I will edit my question to format that part in bold.