# How can I check for which command is run in setup.py?

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I would like to know how to make some code in setup.py conditional on which command (e.g. `install` or `upload`) was run.

Specifically, I'd like to have:

1. An easy way to add "hacks" such as ignoring a particular file in `install`, but no other commands.
2. A recommended/canonical way to add hooks such as running tests before installing.

I have tried reading the [distutils documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/), but it's pretty sparse on details – the distutils.command[.foo] modules are completely undocumented.

For the first point I can check `sys.argv` like mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045802/check-some-requirements-when-running-setup-py-for-install), but that doesn't work when multiple commands are run, like:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist upload
```

so it isn't applicable in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the command instead:

```
from distutils.command.install import install
from distutils.core import setup

def run_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        exec(f.read())

class myinstall(install): # subclass distutils's install command
    def finalize_options(self): # called after option parsing
        # call base class function
        install.finalize_options(self)
        # super won't work because distutils under Python 2 uses old-style classes
        # ignore a module
        self.distribution.py_modules.remove('mymodule')
    def run(self): # called to run a command
        # run tests first
        run_file('path/to/test.py')
        # ^ remember to make sure the module is in sys.path
        # run the real commands
        install.run(self)

setup(
    name='abc',
    py_modules=['mymodule'],
    cmdclass={'install': myinstall}
    # ^ override the install command
)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Does the same code work in 2 & 3?

Comment: @otus: Now it does. :) Turns out they removed execfile in Python 3, so you have to roll your own version.